# PHP array error showing variable not is being Undefined

Tags: php

This code is for illustrative purposes only:

I have this code when the password is correct it ouputs the email address, the password and Password is valid.

When I change $inputpass to any value e.g. xyz the code outputs the email addres and 'Passoword is INVALID' as it should be but it doesn't output the incorrect passoword and gives me the following: Notice: Undefined variable: passkey in C:\xampp\htdocs\login.php on line 36

What I can't understand that it doesn't give me the same whent he password is correct. I can't understand why passkey is not being defined when it is incorrect.

As I mentioned earlier the code is illustrative purpose only - so ignore the scope and I am aware it can be done using MySQL.

```
<?php
$profile["joseph"] = array(
  "email" => "joseph@gmail.com",
  "pass" => "xeta",
  );

$profile["mary"] = array(
  "email" => "mary@yahoo.com",
  "pass" => "byess",
  );

$profile["mario"] = array(
  "email" => "mario@yz.com",
    "pass" => "bye",
  );

$inputemail = "joseph@gmail.com";
$inputpass = "xeta";

//Check email vs username
foreach ($profile as $profilekey => $profileval) {
       if ($profileval["email"] === $inputemail) {
         $emailkey =  $inputemail;
         echo $emailkey; 
       }
}

//Check password vs username
foreach ($profile as $profilekey => $profileval) {
       if ($profileval["pass"] === $inputpass){
         $passkey =  $inputpass;
         echo $passkey; 
       }
}

if(($inputemail == $emailkey) AND ($inputpass == $passkey)){
  echo "Password is valid";
}
else {
  echo "Password is invalid";
}


?>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
$passkey = '';
foreach ($profile as $profilekey => $profileval) {
   if ($profileval["pass"] == $inputpass){
     $passkey =  $inputpass;
     echo $passkey; 
   }
}
```

Likewise:

```
$emailkey = '';
foreach ($profile as $profilekey => $profileval) {
   if ($profileval["email"] == $inputemail) {
     $emailkey =  $inputemail;
     echo $emailkey; 
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Because `$passkey` is only ever defined when the password is correct, inside this if statement:

```
if ($profileval["pass"] === $inputpass){
         $passkey =  $inputpass;
         echo $passkey; 
       }
```

If there is no match, the code never gets inside the above if statement and `$passkey` is never defined, so when it gets down to this point:

```
if(($inputemail == $emailkey) AND ($inputpass == $passkey)){
  echo "Password is valid";
}
else {
  echo "Password is invalid";
}
```

`$passkey` is not defined.

So you will need to define `$passkey` somewhere earlier in your code, possibly as an empty string to start.